# Real-time Tick Filtering

Tags: tick-data

Is anybody aware of any papers regarding tick/quote filtering algorithms. I'm aware of the Olsen stuff, but I'd prefer something with fewer free parameters.

Comment: filtering for what?  Bad ticks?  Big movements? lack of bur or sell side liquidity?

Comment: I'm thinking of bad ticks & big movements.

Answer (score 3):

You could try just the basics:

- Inversion of bid ask spread (`if bid_px >= ask_px`)
- Unusual prints far out (`if bid_px - eps_ticks <= trade_px <= ask_px + eps_ticks`)
- Time sequencing (`if event_time[0] >= event_time[1]`, `0` for most recent)
- Max values (`if volume == 2^64-1`)

There's very few papers out there and I believe all of them are outdated anyway. Some things that used to be positives the past would never happen given the exchange-side technology today and old quote filters would probably give you false positives over artefacts of the modern markets (e.g. fragmented trade reporting).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, would there be any online way of calibrating eps_ticks? (for instance).

Comment: It depends what you're trying to achieve with this filter and how downstream in your application this is, e.g. if this is an 'infrastructural' filter rather than a piece of your strategy logic. An obvious hint is that `eps_ticks` should vary by symbol and time.